# How to properly set A Retrofit response into a MutableLiveData so that it becomes observable

Tags: java, android, retrofit2, android-livedata, mutablelivedata

- **What I'm trying to do :** I am trying to show a list of cities in a `RecyclerView` in the `MainActivity` and whenever a city in the list is clicked a `WeatherDetailsActivity` should fetch a response from the `OpenWeather's API` using `Retrofit`. I'm using `MVVM` architecture.
- **What I've managed to do so far :** I've got the list showing up perfectly and even the response is fetched properly according to a `POJO` model, but when I click on a city it crashes due to `NullPointerException`.
- **TL;DR** : I don't understand why the `return weatherResult;` in the `WeatherRepository.java` always return null.

---

- **Code:**

**WeatherRepository.java**

```
public class WeatherRepository {
    final String TAG = this.getClass()
                           .getSimpleName();

    private static final String WEATHER_API_URL = "https://api.openweathermap.org/";
    private static WeatherRepository weatherRepository;
    private APIService apiService;
    MutableLiveData weatherResult;


    private WeatherRepository() {
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(WEATHER_API_URL)
                                                  .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                                                  .build();
        apiService = retrofit.create(APIService.class);
    }

    public synchronized static WeatherRepository getInstance() {
        if (weatherRepository == null) {
            return new WeatherRepository();
        }
        return weatherRepository;
    }

    public MutableLiveData<WeatherResult> getWeatherData(String city, String appid) {
        apiService.getWeatherData(city, appid)
                  .enqueue(
                          new Callback<WeatherResult>() {
                              @Override
                              public void onResponse(Call<WeatherResult> call, Response<WeatherResult> response) {

                                  if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                                      Log.i(TAG, "onResponse: " + response.body()
                                                                          .toString());
                                      //response.body() gets the value perfectly.
                                      weatherResult.setValue(response.body());
                                  }
                              }
                              @Override
                              public void onFailure(Call<WeatherResult> call, Throwable t) {
                                  t.printStackTrace();
                                  Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: " + t.getMessage());
                              }
                          });

        return weatherResult; //this always return null
    }
}
```

---

**WeatherViewModel.java**

```
public class WeatherViewModel extends ViewModel
{
    private String TAG = this.getClass().getSimpleName();
     private MutableLiveData<WeatherResult> data = new MutableLiveData<>();


    private String APP_ID = /*secret api key*/;


    public void getWeather(String city)
    {
        data.setValue(WeatherRepository.getInstance().getWeatherData(city,APP_ID).getValue()); // this line throws NullPointerException.
        Log.d(TAG, "WeatherViewModel: "+(data.toString()));
    }

    public LiveData<WeatherResult> getCityDetails()
    {
        return data;
    }

}
```

---

**APIService.java**

```
public interface APIService {

    //Weather API
    //http://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London&appid={APP_ID}

    @GET("data/2.5/weather?")
    Call<WeatherResult> getWeatherData(@Query("q") String city,@Query("appid") String appID);

}
```

---

**WeatherDetails.java**

```
public class WeatherDetails extends AppCompatActivity {

    WeatherViewModel viewModel;
    TextView textView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.weather_details);

        textView = findViewById(R.id.weather_info_text);
        viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(WeatherViewModel.class);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        viewModel.getCityDetails().observe(this, new Observer<WeatherResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(WeatherResult weatherResult) {
                textView.setText(weatherResult.toString()); //this line throws NullPointerException
            }
        });
    }
}
```

---

All I want is to return the `Retrofit response` and set it into the `MutableLiveData<WeatherResult>` so that it is observed inside the `WeatherDetails.java` and the UI is updated accordingly.

I don't get why the `return weatherResult;` in the `WeatherRepository.java` always returns `null`

Now I'm not sure how to proceed, I'm at the end of the ropes so I'm asking it here.

Incase you want to look at the entire code [here is the code on github](https://github.com/SandeepGamot/FloTask). Thank you for every and any help.

---

**UPDATE**
I did the following changes to resolve `NullPointerException` and the crash is fixed. [link to diff](https://github.com/SandeepGamot/FloTask/commit/57dd700d2dcf92803aabaec51c919d2d839320e5)

---

**UPDATE 2**
Here is the final [working code](https://github.com/SandeepGamot/FloTask/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/flotask), what did it for me was to get rid of a `MutableLiveData` in my `ViewModel` class and instead use a `public method` in my `ViewModel` as a wrapper to call the repository service call to the `API server`. [Here is the link to the diff](https://github.com/SandeepGamot/FloTask/commit/57779d98f9b25b91c44a4083fdeb32b11df0b530#diff-92427fc97bcc9adc176b996865ad47c0). Thank you to everyone who helped.

Comment: enqueue always runs on a background thread and return works before the task has executed

Comment: Ok so I am aware of .execute() method for Call<T> in retrofit will that help? If not are you aware of any solutions?

Comment: `weatherResult` should be initialized in the method itself, and should be a local variable, and not kept as a field variable of `WeatherRepository`.

Comment: Thank You for your response. So I tried this https://pastebin.com/SMMSvhHM like you said but I got this https://pastebin.com/WZwnnfgN

Comment: Where are you calling WeatherViewMode.getWeather() to trigger the process? You're liveData's value is initialized as null (new MutableLiveData<>()) so it's to expect the very first time it will be null until getWeather() refreshes it.

Comment: @JorgeCevallos It is in the MainActivity:onRecyclerViewElementClick here is the code to it https://pastebin.com/fUCRPZmQ

Comment: Don't re-start the activity after every click. The main idea of liveData/Observable is to get data reactively. The Observer will be called every time so you can update the UI. And try ignoring weatherResult when it's null the first time. Check if it stops being null after you click an item (and not re-start the activity).

Comment: @JorgeCevallos Thank you, I'll try that and update here.

Comment: You'd need to call back asynchronously instead of returning synchronously.